# How to run Landscape oriented Web-Apps on the Tizen 3.0 Feb milestone under Crosswalk?

Tags: open-source, tizen, crosswalk-runtime, tizen-web-app

After creating a number of landscape-oriented Tizen Web Applications, and building and installing on the box with the Feb 1 Tizen release image using Crosswalk and other boxes with previous images of Tizen, I've discovered that web-applications on the February image will not launch successfully unless the weston.ini files are set to a transform of 90, or 'portrait orientation'.

I've been unable to get web apps to launch in landscape and I'm looking for clues. I have compared packages from the october image and a great many of them have changed. I get a timeout when launching with "xwalk-launcher". I have also attempted to launch with app_launcher.

> Service 'org.crosswalkproject.Runtime1' could not be reached: Timeout was reached

I am able to launch these apps successfully in portrait orientation but not in landscape. If you have any ideas about where this problem could be, please let me know. I am looking to find which packages are responsible for the problem.

If you've gotten web-apps running in landscape orientation on HDMI on a VTC1010, how did you do it? Which packages did you change, add, or uninstall? What did you add to, or remove from your configuration files? How did you change your web-apps to counter this specific problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is in the *fullscreen-shell.so*.

I have a working fix going forward. Two changes are required for this to work.

1. remove the line in */etc/xdg/weston/weston-genivi.ini*

`shell=fullscreen-shell.so`

Your apps will launch now but not in fullscreen. To correct this add `--fullscreen` to weston call.

2. Add a parameter `--fullscreen` to line in */etc/session.d/user-session*.

`weston -i0 --log=$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/weston.log --backend=wayland-backend.so --fullscreen`

I would like to know if there are any reasons for fullscreen-shell that I am not thinking of.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to run Landscape oriented Web-Apps on the Tizen 3.0 Feb milestone under Crosswalk at this time.

The Crosswalk team at Intel have verified this as being a Tizen bug. The appropriate JIRA issue numbers are [TC-2501](https://bugs.tizen.org/jira/browse/TC-2501) and [XWALK-4115](https://crosswalk-project.org/jira/browse/XWALK-4115).

For more details: "I've been using the VTC1010 for testing. My primary choice for display output is HDMI. I have noticed that crosswalk isn't developed for multi-screen yet and I wonder if this could be part of the problem. I have been able to get the Landscape to work on VGA and this can help us move forward but our target is HDMI.

I have also been able to get Landscape to work on HDMI but only under the right conditions. When the VGA is connected the apps will launch on the VGA screen from the start. Once the VGA is disconnected apps will fail with the same error message. After reconnecting the VGA screen the apps will launch on the HDMI port.

It appears the VGA must remain connected. If you boot the box without VGA and just HDMI the apps won't start on boot. You cannot launch the apps by hand. You then connect the VGA display and the apps will launch on the HDMI display. I have found if you disconnect the VGA display the app will shutdown. This is some kind of hard dependancy on the VGA display for the VTC1010."